# python-Using urllib to retrieve web content but got differet content from what I got using browser

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler, urllib

I want to write an translation api using  [this site](http://fanyi.youdao.com/), which has many desirable features when deal with sentences with wildcards.

First I use F12 in chrome to see what request url is using to produce the result.
[image: Here is the screen shot:]

I checked that only `salt` and `sigh` changed when I use different inputs.
So I look the js source code to see how `salt` and `sigh` were produced.
Then I use python library `urllib` to send the request and get the response. But the response translation was not the same when I use the browser to get it. For example,

> > Input :"what album was #head_entity# released on?"
> >
> > Output_browser: "#head_entity#发布了什么专辑?"
> >
> > Output_python:"发布的专辑是什么# head_entity?#"

which is clearly different.

This is the code for producing my result:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse 
import json 
import time 
import random 
import hashlib 
def translator(content):
    """arg:content"""
    url = 'http://fanyi.youdao.com/translate?smartresult=dict&smartresult=rule' 
    data = {} 
    u = 'fanyideskweb' 
    d = content 
    f = str(int(time.time()*1000) + random.randint(1,10)) 
    c = 'rY0D^0\'nM0}g5Mm1z%1G4' 
    sign = hashlib.md5((u + d + f + c).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() 
    data['i'] = content 
    data['from'] = 'AUTO' 
    data['to'] = 'AUTO' 
    data['smartresult'] = 'dict' 
    data['client'] = 'fanyideskweb' 
    data['salt'] = f 
    data['sign'] = sign 
    data['doctype'] = 'json' 
    data['version'] = '2.1' 
    data['keyfrom'] = 'fanyi.web' 
    data['action'] = 'FY_BY_CL1CKBUTTON' 
    data['typoResult'] = 'true' 
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode('utf-8') 
    request = urllib.request.Request(url=url,data=data,method='POST') 
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request) 
    d = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
    return d['translateResult'][0][0]['tgt']
translator('what album was #head_entity# released on?')
```

The only thing I think I changed to make the request different to the original page was the `url` argument in the code:

> > My_url = 'http://fanyi.youdao.com/translate?smartresult=dict&smartresult=rule'
> >
> > Original_url = 'http://fanyi.youdao.com/translate_o?smartresult=dict&smartresult=rule'  which gave me an error `{"errorCode":50}`

I checked the header and data parameters one by one but still can't solve the problem. I have no idea why this happened. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check again inserting the `User-Agent` param in the header?

Comment: @Arun Yes, I’ve tried this (100% sure) . Actually I have tried add as many parameters in the header dictionary as possible as long as it does not get an error. The code provided above is a reduced version for simplicity. Thanks for asking, I should have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: looks like a character encoding issue that your browser and python don't think it's the same encoding.

Comment: @inneedofhelp I was use “utf-8” to encode my data which is English. So where to check the encoding used in browser? Or I need to check the encoding one by one until I get the correct result?